# regular expreseion with multimple conditions

Tags: regex

I need to find a regualer expression that contains the following conditions

1. Start with /appl/
2. Does not end with /
3. does not contain a hyphen (-) anywhere

For example:

```
/appl/test01
```

Would be wrong:

```
/appl/test-01
/appl/test01/
/appl/test-01/
```

I have created the following and it does what I need except for the hyphen part

```
^\/appl\/[\W-]+[/][\W-]|\/appl\/[\W-]+$|[^/]$
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using

```js
^\/appl\/[^-]*[^-\/]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/64lk11/1/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\/appl\/` - `/appl/` string
- `[^-]*` - zero or more chars other than `-` as many as possible
- `[^-\/]` - any char other than `-` and `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly

Would it be possible to do the same but avoiding any special character except alphanumeric and underscore?

Comment: @user2983700 I guess `^\/appl\/\w+$` will do.